# C# ASP.net Razor AJAX Call method Not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, razor

First of all, I am NOT using MVC (don't ask why)

From reading other posts on here it seems I need to use a "WebMethod" approach but I cannot seem to get my function to call properly.

The Chrome console gives me a 404 error `"Cannot find /ajax/TestAjax"`. So I know I'm not locating the function correctly. But I can't seem to find where to put it.

Any advice is much appreciated!

**File locations:**

[image]

**jQuery code:**

```
$("#btn_adduser").click(function () {
        var isValid = validateAddUser();
        if (isValid.length > 2) {
            alert(isValid);
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax/TestAjax",
                data: "",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**C# code:  (ajax.cs)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for ajax
/// </summary>
public class ajax
{
    public ajax()
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string TestAjax()
    {
        return "All Good";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[WebMethod]` is a Web Forms feature.
In **ASP.NET Razor Web Pages** ,you can follow [this](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/261/integrating-web-api-with-asp-net-razor-web-pages) link for RESTful services.

Answer (score 1):

`[WebMethod]` is a Web Forms feature; it won't help you.

You can create an ASHX (Generic Handler) file, or use MVC / Web API.

Comment: If I use the Web API approach I assume I would need to add a package and then replace `[WebMethod]` with `[HttpPost]` ?